# TFRecord holding sequence of sequences

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I have a data where each example holds 3 features

- *Feature A*: A scalar, shape = `(,)`
- *Feature B*: A sequence, shape  = `(max_seq_len, 1)`
- *Feature C*: A sequence of sequences, shape = `(max_seq_len, 100)`

Using [this guide](http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/), I manage to store in a TFRecord the features *A* and *B*, but I cant figure out, how in a single `tf.train.SequenceExample` I can hold all the three different features.

Anyone knows how is this achieveable?